# Wpf DataGrid: Null Reference Exception when trying to update data

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid which displays data from an Access database. Basically what I am trying to do is make it so that when the database is added to or updated then I want to show that in the Datagrid.

What I have so far is a timer that will update every 2 seconds:

```
Public Sub New()
    _UserList = New List(Of Users)
    showUsers()
    Tmr.Interval = 2000
    Tmr.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub TimerEventProcessor(myObject As Object, ByVal myEventArgs As EventArgs) Handles Tmr.Elapsed
    showUsers()
    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCpuList")
    OnPropertyChanged("UserList")
End Sub
```

This would normally work, but I am also doing checks on that data which involve looking at the selected row and allowing the user to delete that record. This is where it breaks, basically the selected item will get set every time a row is clicked on but the showUsers() method will set this value to an empty string again.

```
Public ReadOnly Property UserList() As List(Of Users)
    Get
        Return _UserList
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub showUsers()

    Dim SelCpuID As String = ""
    If hasRemoved = True Then
        If _SelectedCpuList.Count <= 1 Then
            _SelectedCpuList.Clear()
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCpuList")
            OnPropertyChanged("UserList")
            hasRemoved = False
        Else
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCpuList")
            OnPropertyChanged("UserList")
            hasRemoved = False
        End If
    End If
    For Each c In _SelectedCpuList
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelCpuID) OrElse SelCpuID.Length = 0 Then
            SelCpuID = c.MachineID
        End If
    Next

    _selUserList = SelCpuID
    _MachineID = SelCpuID

    _UserList = BLL.getUsers()


    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCpuID")
    OnPropertyChanged("machineID")

End Sub
Private _SelectedCpuList As New List(Of Users)
Public Property SelectedCpuList() As List(Of Users)
    Get
        Return _SelectedCpuList
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of Users))

        _SelectedCpuList = value
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCpuList")
        showUsers()

    End Set
End Property
Private _SelectedCpuID As Users
Public Property SelectedCpuID() As Users
    Get
        Return _SelectedCpuID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Users)
        _SelectedCpuID = value

        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCpuID")
        Dim temp As New List(Of Users)
        temp.Add(_SelectedCpuID)
        SelectedCpuList = temp
    End Set
End Property
```

This will loop through everything in _SelectedCpuList (Selected row in data grid) and if the selected string is empty then it will set the selected string to the cpuID of the selected row.

The line `SelCpuID = c.MachineID` is giving me a Null Reference Exception which I believe may be to do with the constant attempts at updating the DataGrid.

So I think this is the wrong approach to make and there must be another way to update data when something is changed or added in the database? Other wise the user will have to hit a refresh button which could be a pain if they forget to do so.

Comment: Looks like you are getting c==null somehow

Comment: Yeah I have no idea how, It should never be null as I am selecting a row!

Comment: Could you please provide more code?

Comment: Just added all the code for all functions that are not for my button events

Comment: Take a closer look to code where you fill SelectedCpuList. Maybe in some cases in list you transform to a SelectedCpuList where are null values